# How do you correct the error 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' in matlab

Tags: matlab

My code:
    A = importdata('befootball.xls','Sheet1','E2:L11');

```
w1 = 0.01;
w2 = 0.1;
w3 = 1;
w4 = 1;
a = A(:,1);
sg = A(:,2);
rg = A(:,3);
c = A(:,4);
p = A(:,5);

for n = 1:10
    f1(n)=w1(n)*c(n) + (w2(n)*p(n)) + (w3(n)*a(n));
end
```

Error:
*Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in fitnessfunctionoutputt (line 33)
sg = A(:,3);*

The same error also comes for rg and subsequently all the variables apart from 'a'.

Is there anyway of solving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your samples of your input data as well. It's difficult to know without it.

Comment: One of your arrays it not large enough, or your indices are to large. Check the sizes.

Comment: Check if you are getting enough data from the `importdata`. It seems `A` doesn't have more than 2 columns there, so `A(:,3)` is throwing *matrix dimensions* error.

Comment: Maybe you can try `disp([ 'size of A is: ', num2str(size(A))] )`. You may even want to see the type of A. It may very well be a cell or struct depending on your data. You should use try the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html). There are too many source of error for us to be able to give the proper help that you need.